# MERN stack app randomly broke after 6 months in production and throws the following error: "TypeError: r.filter is not a function"

Tags: arrays, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku

I wrote a full stack critical application using the MERN stack for a client and it has been running smoothly for over 6 months now. Today, my client notified me that upon logging into the app, the Dashboard view flashes on the screen and then disappears throwing this error: TypeError: r.filter is not a function.

The Dashboard view makes an AJAX call to the back-end and fetches a number of tickets from the database that are then stored in Redux and then categorized and displayed on the browser. There are several array methods used in this component, for example:

```
  const awaiting = tickets.filter(
    ticket =>
      (ticket.status === 'Return to Provider' ||
        ticket.status === 'Require survey') &&
      !ticket.closed
  );

  const unassigned = tickets.filter(
    ticket => ticket.status === 'Unassigned'
  );

  const pending = tickets.filter(ticket => ticket.status === 'Issued');

  const active = tickets.filter(
    ticket =>
      ticket.status === 'On field' ||
      ticket.status === 'Provisioning required by client'
  );

  const complete = tickets.filter(
    ticket =>
      (ticket.status === 'Complete' ||
        ticket.status === 'Complete to activate at a later date') &&
      !ticket.closed
  );
```

The error is thrown at the first .filter method. If I comment that out, the error is thrown at the next and so on. The same error is being thrown wherever there is an array method used and this is the exact error message:

```
TypeError: r.filter is not a function
at t.value (Dashboard.js:99)
at Mi (react-dom.production.min.js:3785)
at Pi (react-dom.production.min.js:3776)
at ji (react-dom.production.min.js:3960)
at Ba (react-dom.production.min.js:5514)
at $a (react-dom.production.min.js:5536)
at Mu (react-dom.production.min.js:5958)
at Cu (react-dom.production.min.js:5925)
at ku (react-dom.production.min.js:5860)
at Xa (react-dom.production.min.js:5787)
```

When I try to access another view on the app where an array method is used to render a list of tickets specifically, I get the same error. But, I am able to access any other view that does not render a list of tickets, there are no errors thrown.

NOTE: This ONLY occurs when I connect to the production database, which has over 2000 tickets (over 30MB of data), regardless of whether I am connecting from my localhost environment or from production environment.

However, when I connect the same code base to my test database (which has 34 tickets), there are no errors thrown and everything runs smoothly.

This is literally the only difference I can identify that is producing this error and crashing the entire app (the number of tickets that the array methods are operating on).

As I said before, the production app was running smoothly for the last 6 months. What would cause such a random app-breaking error like this?

Comment: Did you investigate the network responses? Is the production server returning the correct structured data?

Comment: 30MB data fetch w/o pagination? good joke

Comment: you are not getting the tickets array correctly from backend

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons why `filter()` might not work in your situation. 
Can you specify the network response you are getting ? That would be a good way to start debugging.

There are 2 main failure points at play here:

1. Response is coming wrong from backend or not coming at all (server side fault, which seems like the probable cause because your app suddenly broke)
2. There is something wrong with your client side code

Response from backend can break because of any number of reasons. You can check for:

- SSL Certificate expiry
- Environment Variable mis-function issue
- Response being very large (as you said 30MB, in which case you can use and should definitely use pagination)